# No overload matches this call, on style attribute in jsx typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having the following error style attribute

(No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BoxProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<BoxProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error.)

if I leave { display: 'none' } by it self the problem goes away for some reason.

yet In codesandbox works like charm, but in my module it errors out
any idea what is the general reason for this error ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-vt78m?file=/demo.tsx:605-647

[image]

```js
//State
 const [view, setView] = useState<boolean>(true);
// Box MUI item
 <Box style={!view ? { display: 'none' } : null}>
 </Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the compilation error diagnostic in your post: instead of `null`, use `undefined`:

```ts
<Box style={!view ? { display: 'none' } : undefined}>
```

Comment: working , but why does ts, have an issue with the null here ? if you could elaborate.

Comment: I don't maintain the core React library, so I can't say more than "that's just how it's written". The type for that attribute is defined in the type declaration file. In your CodeSandbox: you can view it by cmd/ctrl + click on the attribute name `style` in your code.